# Put sql query output in variable powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I want to put a counted value from a sql query into a variable of powershell...? If i run the following command:

```
sqlcmd -S "ms-sql-1264" -d "ShellPlus" -q "SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT COUNT(InternalMeasurementID) as number_of_running_measurements FROM [ShellPlus].[dbo].[Measurements] WHERE Archived = 0 AND ClinicalInfo NOT LIKE '%PSG%' AND Classification NOT LIKE '%TEST' AND Classification NOT LIKE '%RESEARCH%' AND Status = 2"
```

I get the result:

```
PS H:\> C:\install\powershell scripts\mail sturen lopend EEG\test_sql.ps1
```

> ```
> number_of_running_measurements
> ------------------------------
>                              0
> ```

but the program won't stop...?

And i want to create an if statement with the value "number of running measurements"

Anyone?

Best regards,
Thijs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017) is different from most Windows applications that it is case sensitive. That is, switches `-q` and `-Q` have different purposes.

```
-q "cmdline query"  
-Q "cmdline query" (and exit)
```

Since lower case q means to query without exit, change it to upper case q for query and exit behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but how do i get my value into a variable...?

Comment: $test = sqlcmd -S "ms-sql-1264" -d "ShellPlus" -Q "SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT COUNT(InternalMeasurementID) as number_of_running_measurements FROM [ShellPlus].[dbo].[Measurements] WHERE Archived = 0 AND ClinicalInfo NOT LIKE '%PSG%' AND Classification NOT LIKE '%TEST' AND Classification NOT LIKE '%RESEARCH%' AND Status = 2" 
$test[2].Trim() This worked!!